# Read More and Read Less button with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a read more button and of course excerpt.

this is my base code to call text `<?php the_content();?>`

I add something for read more but it doesn't work.

```
<?php if($excerpt = $desc->the_content):?>
<?php 
$num_word = 15;
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
echo '<p>' . wp_trim_words($excerpt,15,'...') . '</p>';
echo '<p class="property-content">' . wp_trim_words($excerpt,25,'...') . '</p>';
?>
                        
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: `$excerpt = $desc->the_content` shouldn't be `==` ?

Comment: If the above doesn't help, please expand on "doesn't work" - describe what's happening that should not, or what should happen but does not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

```
<?php if ($excerpt = the_excerpt()): 
                
                $num_word = 5;
                $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
                echo '<p>' . wp_trim_words($excerpt, $num_word, '...') . '</p>';
                ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```